Console Return Undefined when calling click on send button through console js but click does not work
Hi there i am building chrome extension and trying to click on send button.
before write code for it i was testing the simple js code to see if i can simulate clicks on send button.
here are few codes i tried
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.arco-btn.arco-btn-primary.arco-btn-shape-square.m4b-button')[0];    
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
        listener : f Ur(),
        once: false,    // whether the event bubbles
        passive: false, // whether the event can be canceled
        type : "click",
        useCapture: false,
    });
    
    // Dispatch the event
button.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

Simple try:
button.click()

simulating return key
const downEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter', which: 13, keyCode: 13 });
const pressEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter', which: 13, keyCode: 13 });
const upEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter', which: 13, keyCode: 13 });

button.dispatchEvent(downEvent);
button.dispatchEvent(pressEvent);
button.dispatchEvent(upEvent);

but all in vain.
nothing is working.
here is html code of the element
<button data-tid="m4b_button" class="arco-btn arco-btn-primary arco-btn-size-small arco-btn-shape-square m4b-button" type="button">
<span>Send</span></button>

event bind to it.

Please suggest any solution, i tried everything listening to event invoking.
nothing helped
here is how it look like


What does Console Return Undefined in your title have to do with any of this?

when i run the button.click() it returns undefined but does not click.

that's what .click() returns, what did you expect it to return?

whatever it returns, i just want it to work. message should be send. but that is not the case.

I think you'll find you can't manufacture a click like that, unless it's in response to a "user interaction"

Yes i feel website is blocking click through js and only triggers event when clicked by real user. Any tip to mimick real user so to invoke listener

Following the comment section of your post, I assume you want to run a function that sends a message upon clicking a button on the page, or simulating a button click.
Also in response to @JaromandaX's comment, click() can be triggered at any time, even when operating inside of a Chrome Extension.
I'm pretty sure your issue lies in the fact that your <button> tag is never closed. Here's a JSFIDDLE that shows the code fully working with a closed button, a "click" event listener, and a "click" event being launched by the script.
If the link above isn't working, here's the code snippets
<button data-tid="m4b_button" class="arco-btn arco-btn-primary arco-btn-size-small arco-btn-shape-square m4b-button" type="button">
    <span>Send</span>
</button>

const button = document.querySelector(".arco-btn.arco-btn-primary.arco-btn-size-small.arco-btn-shape-square.m4b-button");

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => { // Define your function here, or call an existing one.
    console.log("Just an example")
})
button.click()


No,  closing tag is there on website. What i want is to click it through console , which is possible on other websites. But in my case it does not click.

Which website are you referring to? I'll go check it out myself, see if I can get it working.

tiktok creator send message page , it will be something like this,
https://affiliate-us.tiktok.com/seller/im?creator_id={creator_id}

So finally i was able to figure out, the website where i was injecting click event to button it was using react, so that's why simple click event was not working.
this code worked for me.
function dispatchReactClickEvent(element) {
      console.log('In dispatch event: ',element.textContent);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!element) {
        console.log('No element provided');
        reject('Element not found.');
        return;
      }

      let event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      });
    event.simulated = true; // Indicate that the event is simulated, useful for custom handlers

    // Attempt to find React's internal event handlers attached to the element
    let eventPropagators = Object.keys(element).find(key => key.startsWith('__reactProps$'));
    if (eventPropagators) {
        let clickHandler = element[eventPropagators].onClick;
        if (clickHandler) {
            // Directly invoke React's onClick handler with the simulated event
            clickHandler(event);
        }
    }

    // Dispatch the click event to the element to trigger any other non-React handlers
    element.dispatchEvent(event);

    // Use a timeout to simulate waiting for the event to have its effect
    // Adjust the timeout as necessary based on expected delays for actions to complete
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true); // Resolve the promise after the delay
    }, 500); // Example delay of 500ms
});

}
